# Will the visibility of an Android app released as Open Beta, be same as public release?

Tags: android, google-play

Does releasing an app in open beta decrease its visibility to the public?
I will be launching an android app with open beta where users can download it and even do the purchases. Will it make any difference regarding the visibility of the app in Google Play Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Play doesn't make any guarantees about search visibility on Google Play. [The help docs are here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213). They say

> If you set up an open test, users can find your test app on Google Play. Make sure that your app is ready to be visible on Google Play before choosing this option.

There is the [user facing documentation here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/7003180).

So if you make it open beta, it will be visible in the Play Store, but there are no guarantees on how this will effect search rankings. Also, users will have to opt-in to install it.